# C++ errno 22 received from bind()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, raspberry-pi, errno

*EDIT* I am an idiot, the problem was a misplaced parenthesis thanks for the help guys.

I am trying to get a socket to initialize but I keep on getting errno 22 when I try and bind the socket. I have read through countless tutorials and scoured the database on sockets but I can not for the life of me figure this out. Any of you pro's care to help a newbie out?

My problem seems to be in this block of code:

```
if(bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr) < 0))
        {
            printf("Error binding socket: %d\n", errno);
            return 1;
        }
```

There is no actual program error, but the program prints out that errno was set to 22 and returns 1.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

int serverSock, newSockFd, port; 
unsigned int clientAddrLen;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;

int Server::ServerStart(short int portno)
{
    port = portno;
    if(port < 10)
    {
        printf("Invalid port number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Port valid, creating new socket\n");

    serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(serverSock < 0)
    {
        printf("Error opening socket: %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket open\n");

        bzero((char *)(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr));

        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        printf("Binding socket\n");

        if(bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr) < 0))
        {
            printf("Error binding socket: %d\n", errno);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Socket bound, listening for new connection\n");

            listen(serverSock, 5);

            printf("New connection found\n");

            clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
            newSockFd = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);
            if(newSockFd < 0)
            {
                printf("Error accepting connection: %d\n", errno);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("New Socket is: %d\n", newSockFd);
                return newSockFd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first post so I hope I did it correctly, please feel free to point any thing I did wrong or could have done better(even if it does not pertain to the actual problem, I am always willing to learn).

Comment: If you use [`perror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html) it'll give you a nice description of what `errno` means. I'm guessing 22 means [`EINVAL`](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno), which means your arguments are invalid. It's likely you passing `sizeof(serverAddr) < 0` (which evaluates to 0) instead of `sizeof(serverAddr)` for the last argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you misplaced the closing parenthesis.

Here

```
if(bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr) < 0))
```

you pass `sizeof(serverAddr) < 0` (which is `false` so it's converted to `0`) as the last parameter to `bind` so it obviously fails.

It should be

```
if(bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed parenthesis.
Even if you close parenthesis , and you get error , its probably you passed wrong argument of sizeof( struct sockaddr).

bind assumes 3 parameters and the third parameter is of type in
I have seen people who had passed the value
sizeof (struct sockaddr *) instead of sizeof( struct sockaddr)

Note: Third parameter should be integer , not a pointer to integer